# What's the Best Way to Do Pre-formatted Code Snippets in Slim Templates

Tags: slim-lang

I'm trying to display pre-formatted code snippets using Slim templates in my Ruby on Rails app. To be clear, I'm cutting and pasting code samples between `<pre><code></code></pre>` tags and need them to display with all the proper indentations.

Due to the fact that Slim also makes use of indentations, this makes things awkward. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: And what's the problem? Just pass variable ```code= @code```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've figured it out. I didn't realize multi-line strings could be nested under a single pipe like this:

```
pre
  code
    | 
      # The Greeter class
      class Greeter
        def initialize(name)
          @name = name.capitalize
        end

        def salute
          puts "Hello #{@name}!"
        end
      end

      g = Greeter.new("world")
      g.salute
```